# Dynamic views in couchbase using map reduce

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

This is the map reduce function I am using right now

```
  public static final String UNIQUE_ASSET_COUNT_VIEW = "function (doc, meta) { \n"
  + "  if(doc.type == \"nikhil\") { \n"
  + "emit();
```

I want to make this  dynamic as it will change according to the type of document.
Right now I am not able to do this. Is there any way to achieve this.
I am using Couchbase 5.x

Answer (score 1):

Views are on their way out in Couchbase, you should create an index instead if you are running on +5.5.x.

Since this version, we can push all aggregations down to the index: https://blog.couchbase.com/new-querying-features-couchbase-server/

If you are using Spring data, you could add the annotations @ViewIndexed (if you really want to use views) or @N1qlPrimaryIndexed.

Comment: I am using @ViewIndexed annotation and I am able to create views and indexes but my scneraio is to create an index when certain type of document gets stored into my database i.e based on doc.type. That's why I want to make that if clause dynamic instead of using this hard coded term "nikhil". I want to pass this value through my code.

Comment: Do you have "dynamic" document types? if not, you could also use @N1qlSecondaryIndexed  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.indexing or creating indexes using `bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex()`.